# Linq-to-Sql with Multiple Contains

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

The query below is a simple query with multiple OR conditions, and basically looks to see if the searchString is contained in any of the 3 fields included: ItemID, ItemID2, or ItemDescription.  If the searchString is "3/4 pipe", it will only return records that contain "3/4 pipe".  I need it to return records that contain both "3/4" and "pipe" so that records such as "3/4 steel pipe" or "3/4 copper pipe" or "pipe for 3/4 wire" are included.  Essentially, the result values need to include both words in searchString.  "3/4 copper" or "copper pipe" would not be returned, since neither of them contain both "3/4" and "pipe".

And for an added twist of fun, searchString can have any number of words.

```
IEnumerable<Item> query = from item in context.Items
                                  where item.ItemID.ToUpper().Contains(searchString) ||
                                  item.ItemID2.ToUpper().Contains(searchString) ||
                                  item.ItemDesc.ToUpper().Contains(searchString)
                                  orderby item.ItemClassID, item.ItemID ascending
                                  select item;
        return query.ToList();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently the delimiter in your `searchString` is space character. Therefore, first you need to split the `searchString` into an array of strings:

```
var searchStringList = searchString.Split(' ');
```

Then you can check if any of the specified columns contains all of the items in the string list, for example:

```
searchStringList.All(x => item.ItemID.ToUpper().Contains(x))
```

Finally it would be something like this:

```
var searchStringList = searchString.Split(' ');

IEnumerable<Item> query = from item in context.Items
                                  where searchStringList.All(x => item.ItemID.ToUpper().Contains(x)) ||
                                  searchStringList.All(x => item.ItemID2.ToUpper().Contains(x)) ||
                                  searchStringList.All(x => item.ItemDesc.ToUpper().Contains(x))
                                  orderby item.ItemClassID, item.ItemID ascending
                                  select item;
        return query.ToList();
```

**Update**
As in your comment, the above code complains that local sequence (searchStringList) cannot be used in LINQ to SQL.
One solution that I can propose for that is to use `ToList()` to first get all table records into memory and then do the search on the object. However, you should note that it has performance issue.

```
var searchStringList = searchString.Split(' ');

IEnumerable<Item> query = from item in context.Items.ToList()
                                  where searchStringList.All(x => item.ItemID.ToUpper().Contains(x)) ||
                                  searchStringList.All(x => item.ItemID2.ToUpper().Contains(x)) ||
                                  searchStringList.All(x => item.ItemDesc.ToUpper().Contains(x))
                                  orderby item.ItemClassID, item.ItemID ascending
                                  select item;
        return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, the delimiter is a single space.  However, the specified column must contain all of the elements of the array.  Regardless, I tested this approach and I received the following error:  "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."

Comment: Regarding the first issue, I replaced `Any` with `All` to include only record whose at least one of the specified columns contains all of the elements. And for the error that you are facing, I added the the explanation to the answer.

Comment: Got it.  I'll do some more testing.  I tested iterating through the searchStringList and appending the query results to a master list to be returned, and that works, but as I mentioned, it doesn't ensure all of the elements in the searchStringList are included in a single column.  I believe your suggestion will work, but I am a little concerned about the performance.

Comment: Glad it helped!